# Grab n item in nested array jq

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

I am trying to grab 'n' item from a nested json array. The scenario is that I need to get the IP addresses from newly created cloud instances from my cloud provider so I can perform automation task with ansible. Here is a sample of the json output from the api that my cloud provider gives. (details obscured for privacy and security reasons)

```
[
  {
    "alerts": {
      "cpu": 180,
      "io": 10000,
      "network_in": 10,
      "network_out": 10,
      "transfer_quota": 80
    },
    "backups": {
      "enabled": false,
      "last_successful": null,
      "schedule": {
        "day": null,
        "window": null
      }
    },
    "created": "2022-04",
    "group": "",
    "hypervisor": "kvm",
    "id": 36084613,
    "image": "ubuntu20.04",
    "ipv4": [
      "12.34.56.78",     #<--- Need to grab this public address
      "192.168.x.x"      #<--- and this private address
    ],
    "ipv6": "0000::0000/128",
    "label": "node-1",
    "region": "us",
    "specs": {
      "disk": 81920,
      "memory": 4096,
      "transfer": 4000,
      "vcpus": 2
    },
    "status": "running",
    "tags": [],
    "type": "standard",
    "updated": "2022-04",
    "watchdog_enabled": true
  }
]
```

I need to get the public IP address to I can add the node to an inventory file. So far, I have managed to get the following:

```
$ cat json.json | jq -r '.[0].ipv4'
[
  "12.34.56.78",
  "192.168.x.x"
]
```

I can get what I want by repiping into jq, but I feel there has to be a more elegant way to do so.

```
$ cat json.json | jq -r '.[0].ipv4' | jq -r '.[0]'
12.34.56.78

$ cat json.json | jq -r '.[0].ipv4' | jq -r '.[1]'
192.168.x.x
```

New to posting on StackOverflow so I apologize in advance if someone already answered this on another thread. I looked around and couldn't find what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want:

```
jq -r '.[0].ipv4[]'
```

or perhaps:

```
jq -r '.[].ipv4[]'
```